# java - increasing heap space to maximum limit

Tags: java, memory

So I am using intellij and working on a program. I left my VM options empty and ran the program, it throws `outofmemory:java heap space` exception.

So I decided to ramp up the heap space, by adding `-Xmx1024m`. The program runs halfway and then it throws the same error again. I am basically trying to extract words from a pdf document (has 10 million words) so that's a big file.

I tried increasing the value to `5000m` but it says `invalid maximum heap size the specified size exceeds maximum representable size` . Does anyone know what is the maximum possible size i specify the value so it can run my program completely?

Answer (score 0):

The value of the JVM heap size is directly related to the amount of physical memory in the system.  Set the initial and maximum heap sizes to 4096 to start tuning, because 32-bit operating systems have an address space limit of 4 GB, regardless of the amount of physical memory in the system.

- Talking about default heap size in Java, from Java 6 update 18 there
  are significant changes in how JVM calculates default heap size in 32
  and 64 bit machine and on client and server JVM mode:
- Initial heap space and maximum heap space is larger for improved
  performance.
- Default maximum heap space is 1/2 of physical memory of size upto
  192 bytes and 1/4th of physical memory for size upto 1Gig. So for
  1Gig machine maximum heap size is 256MB 2. maximum heap size will not
  be used until program creates enough object to fill initial heap
  space which will be much lesser but at-least 8 MB or 1/64th part of
  Physical memory upto 1GB.
- for Server Java virtual machine default maximum heap space is 1G for
  4GB of physical memory on a 32 bit JVM. for 64 bit JVM its 32G for a
  physical memory of 128GB

Also be reminded that increasing memory does not help many times, as actual issue resides in code. I would suggest you to use heap analyzer and make sure code has no issues.

Comment: "64-bit operating systems have an address space limit of 4 GB" you mean 32-bit?

Comment: Your answer provide lot of information, but doesn't answer the question "what is max value for max value?".

Comment: Answer is very simple here, there is no max limit for 64 bit systems (bound  by physical memory) , and it is documented

Comment: Yes, but your answer doesn't contain this information. Also in case of 32-bit version of JVM answer will be different, you may want to add it too.

Comment: @talex if one reads all bullet points, and links them together answer is pretty clear .

Comment: So there is no fix for my issue??

Comment: @Daredevil there is no straightforward/ simple answer. As ideal value of memory depends on algorithm implemented

Comment: So in that case, what's the max value that can be set higher than 1024m?

Comment: @Daredevil try using 2048m

Comment: It throws an error: could not create the java virtual machine

Comment: try some value lower than 2048 and greater than 1024